# EVM bytecode debugging jumps

Tags: contract-development, evm, bytecode

How can i determine forehand the destination of `JUMP` for which there is no `PUSH` instruction thst preceeds it and the entries in the code where they where set, when analysing the bytecode?
I looked through the example of https://blog.positive.com/reversing-evm-bytecode-with-radare2-ab77247e5e53 and the tool doesn't point the last `JUMP` mentioned in the post to the respective destination entry `0x62`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the destination of a JUMP is dynamic (though the destination does have to be a JUMPDEST opcode), you can't do it by just analyzing the code. You have to actually run the bytecode to figure out where it is going to jump to.

Comment: Yeah, but in that case, the `JUMP` was a consequence of `PUSH1 0X42` `PUSH1 0X20` and `ADD`. That's what i'm looking for, some tool that tells me what are the entries in the code that are responsible for the `JUMP`, even if it is an opcode like `CALLER` or something of a sort

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a tool that does that very specific job. Even the spot in the bytecode that pushes the value used in the JUMP is dynamic. The best you can do is run the program and, every time a word is pushed to the stack, track the location in bytecode where it happened.

Comment: So there is no symbolic evm available and up and running?